# How to find the full virtual path of an IIS VirtualDirectory?

Tags: python, c#, windows, iis

I'm trying to programmatically get a list of all the applications running on an IIS website, but when I query `VirtualDirectory.Path` I only ever get back "/", even though IIS shows the full path as expected.

I used the following script to reproduce my problem.  I'm using [pythonnet](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/) to interface with the C# API:

```
#! python3

import clr
import os
webAdmin = "system32\\inetsrv\\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll"
clr.AddReference(os.path.join(os.environ["SystemRoot"], webAdmin))
from Microsoft.Web.Administration import ServerManager

def main():
    manager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("localhost")
    site = manager.Sites["Default Web Site"]
    poolName = "test-app-pool"
    manager.ApplicationPools.Add(poolName)
    newApp = site.Applications.Add("/another-test", "C:\\some\\path")
    newApp.ApplicationPoolName = poolName
    manager.CommitChanges()

    print(newApp.VirtualDirectories[0].Path)
    # Output: /

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I expected the output to be "/another-test".  Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.virtualdirectory?view=iis-dotnet) it says VirtualDirectory.Path "Gets or sets the virtual path of the virtual directory relative to its parent".  If I loop through all the applications and all the virtual directories on the site, each of them has a .Path of "/".  How do I get the full virtual path?

Comment: I believe newApp.Path contains what you want

Comment: @Vasya Yes, you're right.  I should have noticed that.  Feel free to submit that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: "I expected the output to be "/another-test"" is the wrong part, as pointed out in the other comment. Beginners on IIS configuration system must read a lot to learn the very basic concepts, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Comment: When using the IIS GUI, I usually create a virtual directory first, then convert it to an application.  That's why I thought the VirtualDirectory would have the path of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is Path property of the [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.application.path?view=iis-dotnet) class, i.e. `newApp.Path` contains what you want.